# Combining standard deviations

Tags: standard-deviation

I'm wondering how to combine the SDs for two results. I have the standard deviations of the baseline results and the SDs of the change from baseline. I'm wondering how to calculate the SD of the endpoint.

How do I do this?

Comment: Can you give a simple example of your situation?

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple formula for the [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance) which is just the square of the standard deviatiotn.
$$\text{Var}(X + Y) = \text{Var}(X) + \text{Var}(Y) + 2\text{Cov}(X, Y)$$

In your case $X$ is the baseline result and $Y$ is the change. The critical thing is that you also need the covariance, which you did not mention.

Just as an additional remark, it is unlikely that the covariance is zero. For example, if your values are scores on some test and the change comes from a special intervention, people with a low baseline often profit more.